# Using include_once and include

Tags: php, class

Sometime I have to use `include_once` and `include` it depend how the page are accessed. For example:

**sales.php**

```
include("class/pdoDatabase.php");
include("class/ClassExample.php");

$obj = new ClassExample();
$obj->getNewItem(1);
```

**ClassExample.php**

```
include_once("class/pdoDatabase.php");

class ClassExample {
  public function  getNewItem($id) { .. }
   public function addNew($id) { .. }
}

// Accessing this file directly via Ajax request 
if (isset($_POST['AddNew'])) {
   $obj = new ClassExample ();
   $obj->addNew($_POST['id']);
 }
}
```

If you access to sales.php which will then load `include("class/ClassExample.php");`, however I have to use `include_once` in the `ClassExample.php` because `pdoDatabase.php` might be already loaded in `sales.php`.
If you access the file directly to ClassExample.php with POST query, it mean it will have to load the file and create an object.

**Problem**:
Problem is when you access to ClassExample.php directly - it could not find class/pdoDatabase.php . It work fine when sales.php load class/pdoDatabase.php file

Comment: Wouldn't changing _all of them_ to `include_once` work? Why worry about the difference when it's almost always a problem to include something more than once.

Comment: Why don't you make autoloader?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Problem is when you access to `ClassExample.php` directly - it could not find `class/pdoDatabase.php` . it work fine when sales.php load `class/pdoDatabase.php` file.

Comment: That's what autoloaders are for. Also, consider moving all class definition files to somewhere your web server cannot serve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a problem with include_once and include difference. This is a problem with relative paths. Include always uses paths relative to called php file. You have this file structure:

```
sales.php
[class]
 - pdoDatabase.php
 - ClassExample.php
```

when you call `sales.php` everything is ok, but when you call `ClassExample.php` it's trying to find `class/class/pdoDatabase.php` which don't exist.

Change include line in your `ClassExample.php`

```
include_once(dirname(__FILE__)."/pdoDatabase.php");
```

and use the same pattern everywhere.

Comment: I was going to ask if sales.php and ClassExample.php are definitely in the same directory, but it looks like they're not and thus the problem.

Comment: Thanks Petr. What if the `ClassExample.php` file located in `Form/Plugin/` for example? So in that case I have to do: `include(dirname(__DIR__) . '/../../class/pdoDatabase.php');` ?

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back Yes, and since PHP 5.3.0, there is that new `__DIR__` constant which is the same as `dirname(__FILE__)` so you don't need to use `dirname(__DIR__)` but just `include(__DIR__ . '/../../class/pdoDatabase.php');` if you are targetting new PHP

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong.

Instead of manually loading each class file, you should be using autoloader, that you initialize in bootstrap stage of your application. Something along the lines of:

```
$root = __DIR__;

spl_autoload_register(function( $className ) use ( $root ){

    $className = str_replace( '\\', '/', $className );
    $filepath = $root . '/' . strtolower( $className ) . '.php';

    if ( !file_exists($filepath) )
    {
        return false;
    }

    require $filepath;
    return true;
});
```

To learn more about this, please read about [`spl_autoload_register()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) in the manual.